# Solve an equation with arbitrary exponents

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, problem-solving

I reduced a system of non-linear equations to a single equation for $c$:

$$\left(\frac{x-c}{y-c}\right)^{w - u} = \left(\frac{x-c}{z-c}\right)^{v-u}$$

I need to solve this equation for $c \notin \{ x, y, z \}$ knowing $x, y, z, u, v, w \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x \neq y, x \neq z, y \neq z$ and $u \neq v, u \neq w, v \neq w$.

Is there any way to solve this equation directly? I would like to avoid iterative algorithms as part of this problem. If there is no direct way to solve the equation, which algorithm would you suggest?

Comment: Just to be clear, we are solving for $c$, right?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yes, I hope I am missing something obvious, I am stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Nah, it's definitely not solvable algebraically.

Comment: It **is** algebraic if $(w-u)/(v-u)$ is rational, but that's not going to help you: the polynomial in $c$ will generally not be solvable in terms of radicals.  If you don't want to use iterative algorithms such as Newton's method, you might have power series solutions in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we multiply all the denominators away, we get

$$(x-c)^{w-u}(z-c)^{v-u}=(x-c)^{v-u}(y-c)^{w-u}$$

For simplicity, let $w-u=a$ and $v-u=b$.

$$(x-c)^a(z-c)^b=(x-c)^b(y-c)^a$$

Before I tackle $a,b\in\mathbb R$, let's look at $a,b\in\mathbb N$.

Unfortunately, for $a,b\ge5$, there exists no closed form solution of $c$ in terms of radicals for general $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$ due to the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).  It follows that we can't expect a closed form for $a,b\in\mathbb R$ either...

To be suggestive, Newton's method should work nicely.  Here, we have

$$c_{n+1}=c_n-\frac{(x-c_n)^{a-b}(z-c_n)^b-(y-c_n)^a}{\left(\frac{a-b}{x-c_n}+\frac b{x-c_n}\right)(x-c_n)^{a-b}(z-c_n)^b-a(y-c_n)^{a-1}}$$